# List of Objects Serialization xml fault

Tags: c#, wpf

I am making a WPF application in which I save list of object on exit of my WPF Application. And get the list of objects on system startup. Everything works fine initially. But Some times it gives the serialization Exception. After getting the exception I looked of the xml serialized file. But it seem to me that the exception was thrown because the xml file was not formed properly. When I corrected it. It again worked fine.

```
public static class IsolatedStorageCacheManager<T>
{
    public static void store(T loc)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile appStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain, null, null);
        using(IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream=appStore.OpenFile("myFile21.xml",FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            serializer.WriteObject(fileStream, loc);
        }
    }
    public static T retrieve()
    {
        T obj = default(T);
        IsolatedStorageFile appStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly | IsolatedStorageScope.Domain, null, null);
        if (appStore.FileExists("myFile21.xml"))
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = appStore.OpenFile("myFile21.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                try
                {
                    obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(fileStream);
                }
                catch (SerializationException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the one or more of the objects you're passing in are not serializable?

Comment: What do you mean by XML file not formed properly? How did you have to correct it to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is make sure that the objects passed to `store` are of a type [supported by the DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx).

The easiest thing to do is check all `store` calls yourself.

You could also create a validation method or even better, see if anyone else has implemented one. This method could validate the `loc` object and return a `boolean` and be called at the beginning of the `store` method inside a [System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx) call so that it will only run on a debug configuration. Note though that this method could be quite tricky because you will have to validate type T for all the cases mentioned in the specification of `DataContractSerializer` and if T is a generic validate T's parameter(s) as well.